# Enable/disable simultaneous audio tracks in the browser

Tags: javascript, html, audio, web-audio-api

I want to play multiple audio tracks at the same time in sync and be able to enable or disable tracks programmatically while playing.

I tried putting multiple audio streams in one mp4 file and then set the enabled property of a track like this:

```js
mySong.audioTracks[n].enabled
```

But that technique is currently only [supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=audiotracks) in IE and Safari.

Is this something that can be done with the Web Audio API which seems to have better browser support?

Answer (score 1):

For a possible WebAudio solution, assume you have your mp4 file decoded into an `AudioBufferSource`, `s`, with `n` channels.

Then:

```
var splitter = context.createSplitter(n);
s.connect(splitter);

for (k = 0; k < n; ++k) {
  gains[k] = context.createGain();
  spitter.connect(gains[k], k, 0);
  gains[k].connect(context.destination);
}

// To disable channel m:
gains[m].gain.value = 0;
// To re-enable channel m:
gains[m].gain.value = 1;
```

You can get fancier by having each channel fade in and fade out too.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [HTML5 Audio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio), you can use the `.play()` and `.pause()` commands as detailed in [MDN's guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video).

Let's say you have a page with five HTML5 Audio elements, each with the class `.song1`. If you are wanting to stop and start all tracks at the same time, you could assign buttons to run:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("song1").play();
```

and

```
document.getElementsByClassName("song1").pause();
```

If you are wanting to mute a track whilst the others continue to play, you can set it's volume to 0 programatically too:

```
getElementsByTagName("audio")[0].volume=0; <!-- Mute track 1 -->
```

or

```
getElementsByTagName("audio")[2].volume=0; <!-- Mute track 3 etc -->
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The problem with this technique is that there is no guarantee the tracks will start and stay in sync.

Comment: I've never used this method before so I'm not aware of it's drawbacks. What would cause the audio to become out of sync?